# How do I copy lines following a tag in a python script?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to copy lines a certain number of times following a certain tag.

If I have a text file like the following:

```
##TextLines##
Hi
Hello
##TextLines##
```

How do I erase the tags and copy the line once?

The end text file would look like:

```
Hi
Hello
Hi
Hello
```

Right now, I have a regular expression to find the tags and replace them with a blank newline character. I know most line-by-line reading is done using a for loop after opening a file. However, I don't want to process the specific line read, but the lines after. Any ideas?

Edit: There could be multiple tags and untagged text. For instance:

```
Hi
##CopyLine1##
Hello
##CopyLine1##
Greetings
##CopyLine2##
Howdy
##CopyLine2##
Hola
```

would become:

```
Hi
Hello
Hello
Greetings
Howdy
Howdy
Hola
```

Comment: Your question is not very precise. Are the tag lines used like opening and closing brakets? How should the output look like if there's some text before your first sample line and/or after the last one?

Comment: Yes, the tags are like opening and closing brackets. If there is text before or after, it should still be written to the new file, but only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job

```
import re 
regex = re.compile("^##.*##\n$")
out = open("result.txt","w")
matchfound = True
inmatch =False
for line in open('myfile.txt'):
   if regex.match(line):
       matchfound = True
   else:
        matchfound = False
   if matchfound and not inmatch:
       inmatch = True
       content = []
   elif matchfound and inmatch:
       inmatch = False
       out.write ("".join(content))
   elif inmatch:
       content.append(line)
       out.write(line)
   else:
       out.write(line)
out.close()
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

```
def isTag(line):
    return line.startswith('##')

class LineHandler(object):
    def normalLine(self,line):
        if isTag(line):
            self.lineHandler = self.insideTag
        else:
            print line

    def insideTag(self,line):
        if isTag(line):
            self.lineHandler = self.normalLine
        else:
            print line
            print line

    def __init__(self,path):
        self.lineHandler = self.normalLine
        for line in file(path):
            self.lineHandler(line.strip())

LineHandler('lines.txt')
```

Comment: this program looks pretty however it repeat the lines inside tags immediately and the original poster asked to repeat it by block